# Converting month number to month name

Tags: reactjs, datatables

I'm in struggle trying to convert a month number that i'm getting from API to month name and then render the month name in Datatable.

**Example:**

month (1) => "January"

month (2) => "February"
...etc

For that, i created **this function**:

```
function getMonthName(monthNumber) {
    const date = new Date()
    date.setMonth(monthNumber - 1)
    return date.toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' })
  }
```

It works fine if i provide `monthNumber` correctly.

Now i would like to use this function inside month column (so it **will show month names** instead of month numbers).

**What i'm expecting is**: getting different month names at each row successively.

**What i'm getting is:** table always show January only on all its rows.

I reproduced my issue here:
**Sandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-goldberg-xhqvjm-forked-wwq3m0?file=/src/components/tables/SalesTable/SalesTable.jsx

Comment: I think the issue here is that your `map()` function runs through all options, and sets the state, but that gets overwritten on each row. Your return is outside the map so it takes the last setting of the `useState` which is January - you need to return the row inside the `.map()` if you can - I'm not familiar with mui libs so can't help further

Comment: customBodyRender function is outside of the map function that is why it is not returning the updated value,try maping this function

Comment: @AbdulQadir do you mean i should map customBodyRender ?

Comment: yes,map the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the js-date helper library. I am using date-fns.

[Supported formats](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/format)

```js
npm install date-fns --save


import {format} from 'date-fns'


// Let say its January
const month = 1


// date can be anything
const date = `1970/${month}/07`

const monthName = format(new Date(date), 'LLLL')
```

Comment: would you kindly modify my sandbox to match your answer? so i can see the fix working? maybe i'm wrong.